# 16.04 Cannot run apt-get anything, always get an error

Tags: apt, kernel

I get this error:

```
$ apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 227614 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.275' not found (required by sort)
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by sort)
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.275' not found (required by sort)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to remove the offending package with dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
(Reading database ... 227614 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.275' not found (required by sort)
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by sort)
sort: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.275' not found (required by sort)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
```

Can't install libc (not sure why it's not there) b/c I can't run `apt-get`.

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy libc6 coreutils linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
libc6:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
coreutils:
  Installed: 8.25-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 8.25-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 8.25-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0-53.74
  Candidate: 4.4.0-53.74
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0-53.74 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster updated the post with this info, thanks for taking a look

Comment: a few warnings but it succeeded, thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah i had one other certificate issue which there were plenty of posts for, now apt-get is totally fixed, no warnings, no errors, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the packages `libc6` and/or `coreutils` are corrupted. To fix the issue you need to reinstall them without the help of Apt package operations.

1. Download the `libc6` and `coreutils` package files into a temporary directory (or wherever you'd like to keep them until the end of their installation):

   ```
   cd /tmp
   apt-get download libc6 coreutils
   ```
2. Install them:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i {libc6,coreutils}_*.deb
   ```
3. Fix the remaining packaging issues with Apt:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```